# Exporting RPT to PDF version 1.3 in Crystal Reports 10.5.3700

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, export

I'm using Crystal reports that is embedded in Visual Studio 2008. I'm generating a report which is when exported to PDF I get the PDF file of Version PDF 1.2. I need to get this exported  PDF file to be of version PDF 1.3 or higher. I'm using the Report viewer to generate the report. Is there any way to implement this in Reports itself. My Crystal reports version is 10.5.3700.0. Kindly help me out to obtain the PDF 1.3 or higher versions ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually upgraded my Crystal report verion to get the PDF version higher than 1.2.